# Filling cells with colours

Tags: tables, color

I want to replicate the following result:

[image]

Here's what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\definecolor{color}{RGB}{196,0,98}


\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{color}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Crimes and criminals} \\
\hline
Crimes & Criminals & Verbs \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I want to fill the cells, but I think it will need a more eleborated code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `rowcolor` command which comes to the rescue:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{color}{RGB}{196,0,98}


\begin{document}

\arrayrulecolor{color}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
\hline
\rowcolor{color}
\multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\color{white}Crimes and criminals} \\
\hline
\rowcolor{color}
\color{white}Crimes &\color{white} Criminals &\color{white} Verbs \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
 &  &  \\
\hline
 &  &  \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

with result:

[image]

**EDIT**
The command is defined in the `colortbl` package which is automatically loaded by the table option of the `xcolor` package (thanks @Bernard)

Comment: Needless to load `colortbl` with the `[table]` option of `xcolor`.

Comment: @Moriambar Thank you. It's almost what I want. Can you see the white lines below the words *crimes and criminals*? How can you add them?

Comment: @Ustanak simply use `\arrayrulecolor{white}` before the white `hline`s, and switch back with `\arrayrulecolor{color}` afterwards